# Displaying year from DATE field in classic email template

Tags: email-template

How to display Year from Date in the email template. I tried using `YEAR({!Opportunity.CloseDate}` but it's not working. I did a workaround by creating a new field to store YEAR and used it in the email template.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Text type formula field - `TEXT(YEAR(closeddate()))`, and add it as a merge field in your email template.

Comment: its working fine.. thanks